# On-click transitioning <ul> does not respond

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a responsive navigation which should display a menu when a button is clicked. When it is clicked, the `ul` containing the navigation list is added a class (`.show-nav`) to by jQuery/JS. When this happens a CSS-rule for `.show-nav` changes the `opacity` and `top`-values, so that the `ul` comes down. I tried adding a transition to this, but the `ul` refuses to respond to that.

On the other hand, I also have a `header`-element, which changes the `background-color` when a certain y scroll value is reached (also done by JS). This works in the exacly same way as the latter, by adding a class to the `header` and having the CSS applying a `background-color`.

```js
function toggleClass(jqo, c) {

  var o = $(jqo);
  if (!o.hasClass(c)) {
    o.addClass(c);
  } else {
    o.removeClass(c);
  }

}
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

header .mobile-list {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-header .mobile-list {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 90px;
  right: 0;
  top: -50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #005163;
  transition: top 2s, opacity 2s;
}

.show-nav .mobile-list {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.compact {
  background-color: #005163;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <button class="hamburger" onclick="toggleClass('.hamburger', 'is-active'); toggleClass('header', 'show-nav')" type="button">
      <span class="hamburger-box">
        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
      </span>
    </button>
    <ul class="mobile-list">
      <li><a href="">PHYSICS</a></li>
      <li><a href="">CHEMISTRY</a></li>
      <li><a href="">BIOLOGY</a></li>
      <li><a href="">MATH</a></li>
      <li><a href="">TOOLS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

`.compact` is assigned by JS, just like `.show-nav`. But `header` is responding to the `transition` and the `ul` is not!
*Note that `.mobile-header` is active in every case, so that's no concern.*

I also concluded that the `ul` does respond to all other CSS, just not the transition. I've looked at other websites ([dashlane.com](http://www.dashlane.com)) that have the same kind of navigation system and tried to copy it's structure, but without much avail. How can I achieve the `ul` having a transition and why does my `header` react where my `ul` doesn't?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Added transition line in CSS under `.mobile-header .mobile-list`.
EDIT: Added jQuery code.

Comment: provide a working demo, at least add your jquery code !

Answer (score 1):

You have to know that the css `display` property cannot be animated,

So you have to try another solution, best thing at the meanwhile is the `visibility` and `opacity` properties.

just remove the `display: none / display: block` and replace it with:

```
/*Element style when it's hidden*/
.elementStyle {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
/*Element style when it's visible*/
.elementStyle {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```js
function toggleClass(jqo, c) {

  var o = $(jqo);
  if (!o.hasClass(c)) {
    o.addClass(c);
  } else {
    o.removeClass(c);
  }

}
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.mobile-header .mobile-list {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 90px;
  right: 0;
  top: -50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #005163;
  transition: top 2s, opacity 2s;
}

header .mobile-list {
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  /*Add whatever transition you want*/
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
}

.show-nav .mobile-list {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.compact {
  background-color: #005163;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <button class="hamburger" onclick="toggleClass('.hamburger', 'is-active'); toggleClass('header', 'show-nav')" type="button">Test Button
      <span class="hamburger-box">
        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
      </span>
    </button>
    <ul class="mobile-list">
      <li><a href="">PHYSICS</a></li>
      <li><a href="">CHEMISTRY</a></li>
      <li><a href="">BIOLOGY</a></li>
      <li><a href="">MATH</a></li>
      <li><a href="">TOOLS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: This works great, although the transition does not work when I try click my button. Any idea of fixing this as well?

Comment: if you mean that you want a transition on click, you have to add `:active` but I don't prefer this, if you want you could add a transition on hover, add this `button.hamburger{background: red;transition: 1s;}button.hamburger:hover {background: green;}`

Comment: the click part is achieved by changing a class with JS, therefore different styles get appied (in this case `top` and `opacity`). If that is changed back 
(the class gets removed and orevious styles get appied) there should be another transition happening. There should be one when the `ul` appears and one when the `ul` dissappears. Now there's only a transition when the `ul` appears.

Comment: so what styles do you wish to add?